# How to blend two RGB unsigned byte colors stored as unsigned 32bit ints fast?

Tags: c, performance, colors

Given 2 RGB colors stored as 32bit ints (8bits of alpha can be ignored or set to `0xff`).

Whats the fastest way to blend them using a 3rd integer from 0-255.

---

Here is a naive implementation which simply interpolates the values as ints:

```
int32_t rgb_blend(uint32_t src, uint32_t dst, uint32_t blend) {
    const uint32_t iblend = 255 - blend;
    union {
        uint32_t u32;
        struct { uint8_t
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
            a, b, g, r;
#else
            r, g, b, a;
#endif
        } u8;
    } out, *s = (const void *)&src, *d = (const void *)&dst;

    out.u8.r = (uint8_t)((((uint32_t)s->u8.r * iblend) + ((uint32_t)d->u8.r * blend)) / 255);
    out.u8.g = (uint8_t)((((uint32_t)s->u8.g * iblend) + ((uint32_t)d->u8.g * blend)) / 255);
    out.u8.b = (uint8_t)((((uint32_t)s->u8.b * iblend) + ((uint32_t)d->u8.b * blend)) / 255);
    out.u8.a = 0xff;
    return out.u32;
}
```

---

This doesn't have to be totally accurate, some rounding bias to get some extra performance is fine. `(i / 256)` rounds down for eg but can be replaced with `(((i * 2) + 255) / (2 * 255)` to round at `0.5` while only using integer operations.

---

Notes:

1. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102692) is similar, but am asking about RGB colors, not RGBA alpha blending.
2. While the question isn't architecture spesific, would be interested in common architectures - AMD-64, ARM-64 for eg.

Comment: What machine are you targeting?

Comment: The reason why your code is slow is because operator `/` is slow. So you can estimate `x/255` by `x>>8` or `x/256` as in the answer by @ideasman42, or use `x*257/65536` or `((x<<8)+x)>>16` which gives you a good estimate at `x/255.0039`.

Answer (score 1):

Colors can be blended using only uses add, subtract, multiply and bit-shift (no branches or type conversion):

```
uint32_t rgb_interp(uint32_t src, uint32_t dst, uint32_t t) {
    assert(t <= 255);
    const uint32_t s = 255 - t;
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
    return (
        (((((src >> 0)  & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 0)  & 0xff) * t) >> 8)) |
        (((((src >> 8)  & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 8)  & 0xff) * t)     )  & ~0xff) |
        (((((src >> 16) & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 16) & 0xff) * t) << 8)  & ~0xffff) |
        0xff000000
    );
#else
    return (
        (((((src >> 24) & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 24) & 0xff) * t) << 16) & ~0xffffff) |
        (((((src >> 16) & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 16) & 0xff) * t) << 8)  & ~0xffff) |
        (((((src >> 8)  & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 8)  & 0xff) * t)     )  & ~0xff) |
        0xff
    );
#endif
}
```

RGBA version for reference:

```
uint32_t rgba_interp(uint32_t src, uint32_t dst, uint32_t t) {
    assert(t <= 255);
    const uint32_t s = 255 - t;
    return (
        (((((src >> 0)  & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 0)  & 0xff) * t) >> 8)) |
        (((((src >> 8)  & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 8)  & 0xff) * t)     )  & ~0xff) |
        (((((src >> 16) & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 16) & 0xff) * t) << 8)  & ~0xffff) |
        (((((src >> 24) & 0xff) * s +
           ((dst >> 24) & 0xff) * t) << 16) & ~0xffffff)
    );
}
```